# storing array into variable vba

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a UDF that returns a row vector. I would like to use the results of the said UDF in another function. Thus I would like to use a variable to store the array results to be used as input in second function. When I want to recall an element of the variable, I would get an error "Object required".

```
u = test()
x = u.Item(4)
```

What is missing in my code? Thanks

Comment: Please show how `u` and `x` are declared, and what `test()` actually returns, i.e. how that returned array is declared inside the function.

Comment: `Item` is used for collections which are not the same as arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the index of the array without the `Item` property (this does not exist for arrays) like so:

```
u = test()
x = u(4)
```

Comment: I now encounter a "Subscript out of range". However, I tried transposing the test() function, and it works. Any thoughts?

Comment: `Item` does exist in VBA for Collections, but not for arrays.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Thanks, have updated to reflect your comment.

Answer (score -1):

As the other posts mention - you would not use the .Item property for an array in VBA. As such, you would simply do:

```
u = test()
x = u(4)
```

As for your question regarding why you need to transpose the function, but here's some guidance:

VBA doesn't really handle one-dimensional arrays super well. As such, depending on what you're trying to do with it, you often have to transpose the array into a single "row". I believe that it's basically the equivalent of changing.

`x = u(n)`
into
`x = u(1,n)`

Comment: I have amended my answer to address both the original question, as well as the follow-up question regarding why one needs to transpose the array.